# Cant Close Windows, app already quit

Tags: macos, applications, bug

I am running a 2019 macbook pro with GIMP 2.10 installed

For some reason, gimp's windows will stay open, even after the app is quit

how can I close these windows?

Comment: can you relaunch the app and then try to close the window first and then quit again? I recall my son having issues with a java-based app that left windows "open" but unable to be interacted with. I had him reboot and tried a couple other things (which I don't recall as this was a couple years ago)... I believe ultimately we were able to force the window to close first, and then quit.

Comment: if it becomes a persistent problem, you might be able to make a simple applescript which would control the window and then quit the app. I've done similar things in the past with regard to moving the windows to specific coords on my second monitor, and then resizing it, all per a single applescript. if you can find the "name" of the window, you should be able to control it.

Comment: How did you determine the app wasn't running? I'd look in /Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor for the app.  You could restart the finder command +option + esc.  When you quit the finder, it will restart where it left off.

Comment: @historystamp Activity monitor will not open

Comment: Well, you have other issues too. I'd suggest you reboot. Start activity monitor before you do anything else. If it doesn't start, try a safe boot. Shutdown your machine.  Hold down the shift key.  Poweron.  The boot up will take longer than normal because the filesystem on the startup drive is being checked and repaired as needed.   All about safe mode including what features and apps safe boot leaves out. 
      http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455  You may have other issues or you could go on a wild goose chase tracking down the problems with safe boot.

Comment: what version of macos.  Verify that all apps work under your version of macos.  I suspect you have catalina. A lot of old apps will not work under catalina.

Comment: @historystamp  the app does not show up in any of the places i checked: `force quit menu`, `dock` or with `terminal`. And yes, I have macOS Catalina

Answer (score 1):

I face similar problem with octave-GUI.

I run

```
killall -9 octave 
killall -9 octave-gui
```

twice to get rid of that.

So you can run

```
killall -9 GIMP
```

Make sure you're using case sensitive name of the app.

Comment: this returns `No matching processes belonging to you were found` GIMP is called GIMP-2.10

Comment: when I ran `pkill g` it quit GIMP. why would this happen?

Comment: @FBISurveillanceVan you should search activity monitor for correct, case sensitive name of the process. Also PID can be used, but I’m not sure.

Comment: @FBI Surveillance Van  man pkill has the synonym of pgrep.  This suggests the command does a scan on the name.